# PGAdmin4: Can't prevent browser for opening - archlinux

Tags: postgresql, browser, archlinux, pgadmin

I'm using pgadmin4 and local postgresql server on my Arch Linux. But there is this annoying "feature" that I can not found a way to dissable.
Everytime I start up my system and login to my account something start GoogleChrome ( it's my default web browser) with a only one new tab Pgadmin4 local page - http://127.0.0.1:37937/browser/. And all my pinned tabs are gone!
How can I stop that thing, I've already tried to put another "browser command" in to the "config" from tray notification icon, but it changed the browser only if i clicked on it. When login it start up again google chrome.

Comment: PGadmin runs in your browser as of PGadmin 4 version 3.0 so if you start PGadmin you will be starting your browser.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, in my case was the process kdeinit5 (I'm using KDE) that started the process because of session restore on desktop login.

So I just had to go in **Kde System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Desktop Session** and fill `/usr/lib/pgadmin4/runtime/pgAdmin4` in the input field labeled *"Applications to be excluded from sessions"*.

If you are using some other DM you may have a similar configuration option in whichever way your DM is configured, a look at the docs may help.